# What is the difference between a variant and a variation?

Tags: word-choice, differences, nouns

I designed a logo for a client. He liked the idea it presented, but wanted to see alternative ways to represent its idea, so I came up with several new designs of similar concept. I now have to package the new designs into a presentation document, and when it came to titling its sections, I wondered: are the new designs variants of the initial one, or are they variations?

Comment: In your context, only a pedant would claim any difference. In other contexts, *variant* can be an adjective, but *variation* can't.

Comment: They are *variations* not *variants*. Give it a thought and read your question (the specific case) and wonder why. The choice is easy so I am not telling it right away.

Comment: Only after fruitlessly puzzling over it did I post the question in the first place, @Kris. Even after a re-read, I would guess _variant_, if I had to pick one, as that sounds more like a specific element, e.g. a logo design, rather than the action of the design being made. (As I understand cHao to be saying.) But I get side-tracked wondering whether the logos can consistently claim either term, or whether it all depends on how I'm constructing the sentence in which I refer to them. All that to say, I don't see how you got to your conclusion. I hope you're willing to share.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Very strictly speaking, variation is change, and a variant is one of the forms resulting from the change.

The use of **variation** to mean **variant** is so common, though, that only a hardcore pedant would ever even recognize a difference in that context, much less say either one is incorrect.

Comment: Even a pedant might choke on "variants on a theme" rather than "variations on a theme".

Comment: @TheMathemagician: Indeed.  But he'd typically say "variants *of* a theme" instead, if he were pedantic enough to recognize a difference between the two words in this context.

Comment: Makes sense. Though by these definitions, it's hard to think of an example use case of the word *variation* in everyday speech. I can see it in a technical context, e.g., "The number of letters in American first names has a higher variation this decade than last." But can you provide some colloquial examples?

Comment: @chharvey: The phrase "variations on a theme", as mentioned in these comments, is rather common. Others don't immediately jump out at me, but some dictionaries have examples. (Merriam-Webster, for one, gives the example "the movie begins with a somewhat irreverent variation on the Nativity story".) There's more examples of variation as change. Either way, it does seem more a highbrow word.

Comment: Is there a parallel between *mutation* and *mutant*?  Because that's easy for me to understand.  Mutants (X-Men, turtles, etc.) are the results of mutations (changes) to their DNA.

Comment: @istrasci Interesting

Answer (score 6):

Coming from a technical perspective, if I report that I tackled a problem using a **variant** of Algorithm A, then this variant is most likely one that other people have used before and there is literature on its use. If instead I say I was using a **variation** of Algorithm A, then the existing variants of Algorithm A didn't meet the particular requirements of my problem and I therefore needed to create my own adaptation. People after me might decide to call this a variant of Algorithm A, if they deem it close enough to the original.

**Caution: I'm not a native English speaker.**

Comment: I think this is right. You can have several different variants of a gene, which implies they are known as the possible values it can take; or you can have a variation of a gene, which means it has mutated in some way. Variant implies being a member of a set, often a known set; variation means something which has changed.

Answer (score 4):

A variation is something that differs from a standard or from something considered normal, while a variant differs from other things in its own class--that is, it's not something that necessarily differs from a norm or standard. Source: *Garner's Modern American Usage*.

Comment: Absolutely spot on.

Answer (score 0):

I have understood,or
misunderstood that a variant was a specific and defined variation.Omicron is a variant of Covid 19.There will be a more potent variation to come.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).